# Multi threaded Selenium WebDriver vs Selenium Grid

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I am a newbie to Selenium and am using Selenium to navigate to multiple pages of the same website simultaneously while maintaining a session. I can create a controller in the following 2 ways:

1. The controller initiates **Selenium WebDriver** in a multithreaded environment (1 driver instance per each thread, as WebDriver is not thread-safe. Reference: [Selenium Grid, how to utilize WebDriver with ThreadSafeSeleniumSessionStorage.session()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13057423/selenium-grid-how-to-utilize-webdriver-with-threadsafeseleniumsessionstorage-se))
2. Controller uses **Selenium Grid**

I understand Selenium Grid supports distributed execution by using a hub-node concept; but what are main benefits I would be getting as compared to Option 1.

I see people using Option 1, but facing some issues. Reference: [Multiple WebDriver instances in Selenium without Grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23214254/multiple-webdriver-instances-in-selenium-without-grid)

Is it recommended to use Grid over Selenium WebDriver in a multithreaded environment? If so, why?
Also, would Selenium Grid take responsibility of cleaning any stale browser instances in its nodes (out of the box)?

Comment: It all depends. Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve, first: are you trying to test multiple browsers / platforms; are you attempting to do load testing; are you simply trying to reduce the duration of an existing test suite; and how many sessions do you plan/hope to have running at once (per machine)?

Answer (score 6):

I feel like your misunderstanding the purposes of WebDriver, Grid and a multi-threaded environment.

Selenium WebDriver is just a test framework that kicks off tests onto a browser. It uses drivers such as geckodriver, and chromedriver to open (and close) browser instances and then hits those instances with actions.

Selenium Grid is a stand-alone server that will run your WebDriver tests remotely on a node and reports back. So if you wanted to use another machines resources to run your test-suite you would be able to do so. It also allows you to combine multiple machines resources by assigning each a node and Selenium Grid will distribute your tests evenly.

---

As far as your questions about multi-threading,

> Is it recommended to use <s>Grid over</s> Selenium WebDriver in a multithreaded environment?

Grid is just a remote-runner of WebDriver. WebDriver is the test-framework. I assume your goal is to reduce your test-suite's run-time by running tests in parallel? Parallel testing can be done on your local machine using WebDriver or can be configured on a Selenium Grid. In my experience, I have gotten more lucky on my local machine than on Grid but both essentially face the same problem. **The main danger for parallel testing using WebDriver is [thread-safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261683/what-is-meant-by-thread-safe-code).** JUnit 4.7 onwards and Test-NG RELEASE allow for parallel testing. *I highly suggest using Test-NG instead of JUnit for this purpose.*

To prevent concurrency issues, your main goal will be to make all your shared resources isolated within each thread. A secondary goal is to limit the scope of all variables to its method. This can be done using a static instance of [ThreadLocal](https://www.baeldung.com/java-threadlocal) It is also really useful to force the initializing of driver instances to be frozen in synchronized methods.

### Creating Resources

```
public class DriverFactory {

    private static String grid = "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub";
    public static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();

    public static synchronized void newDriver() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); // Assuming Chrome use
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");

        // USE THIS FOR LOCAL
        // tlDriver.set(new ChromeDriver(options));

        // USE THIS FOR GRID
        try {
            drivers.set(new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(grid),options));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static synchronized WebDriver getDriver() {
        return drivers.get();
    }
}
```

### Test Class

```
public class GoogleTest {
    @BeforeMethod
    public void setup() {
         DriverFactory.newDriver();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https:\\www.google.com");
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Google");
    }

    @Test
    public void test2() {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https:\\www.google.com");
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getTitle(), "Google");
    }


    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() {
        WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

### TestNG.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<!-- thread-count should be = to maxSessions on your Grid -->
<suite name="Whatever" parallel="methods" thread-count="5">
  <test name="Sample">
    <classes>
      <class name="GoogleTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

**Source**: [Making your Tests Thread-Safe](https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-parallel-tests-grid-testng/), [Full Guide](https://www.swtestacademy.com/selenium-tutorial-java-junit/) 
**Versions Used:** *TestNG 6.14.3, Selenium 3.11, Selenium Grid 3.14.3*

> Also, would Selenium Grid take responsibility of cleaning any stale browser instances in its nodes (out of the box)?

Selenium Grid has timeout and a browserTimeout features to free up nodes and close browser instances. Although in my experience I would implore you to control any expected timeouts in your test-cases and have WebDriver close the browser instance, not Selenium Grid. You really want to prevent this from happening and eliminate all causes of un-expected hanging. Test-suites are designed to be quick feedback and are only useful if failures are indicative of an actual failure, not just a dirty test-suite. Also stale nodes/browsers can force you to have to constantly reset your grid + nodes which is a major detriment.